# When loading the heplots, the R shut down

Tags: r, function

I have a problem with the package "heplots". When I load this package.
The R will show the stop in the upper right corner and shut down.
After loading the "broom" package, the situation is the same.
I have no idea about this issue.
[image]

This package can be used to test boxM and conduct the DDA.

Comment: Try reinstalling the packages, or look up the GitHub websites for each package and install development versions in case its due to a bug that is fixed in the developer version (which are more recent but often less stable)